# lxc-start: No cgroup mounted on the system

Tags: debian, lxc

Trying to start a Linux container, I get the following:

```
lxc-start: No cgroup mounted on the system
```

OS is Debian 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LXC (or other uses of the [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) facility) requires the cgroups filesystem to be mounted (see §2.1 in the [cgroups kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt)). It seems that as of Debian wheezy, this doesn't happen automatically.

Add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup defaults
```

For a one-time thing, mount it manually:

```
mount -t cgroup cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Answer (score 0):

For `lxc` in Debian Wheezy I use in `/etc/fstab`:

```
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup defaults,blkio,net_cls,freezer,devices,cpuacct,cpu,cpuset,memory,clone_children 0 0
```

In `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet cgroup_enable=memory,namespace"
```

(& don't forget to run `update-grub`)

It is also possible to run [LXC 1.0.7 on Debian Wheezy](https://serverfault.com/questions/644796/missing-packages-after-clean-debian-install/652155#652155)

[image]